# How to store multiple rows within a variable, to use it as JSONArray in android studio

Tags: php, android

I am trying to mark some points on my maps app, points that have the coordinates stored in a database. I have managed to solve the java issues with the `JSONArray`, but my problem right now it's that the `PHP` sends from the database only one row, not all of them as an array. I have tried to store them in one variable, tried to implement `implode`, but still couldn't manage to send all the rows to the app. On the app, JSONArray is supposed to get the data from `location`.

.php code that sends only 1 row:

```php
$problema = $_POST['problema'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT latitudine, longitudine, tip_problema FROM alerte WHERE tip_problema = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $problema);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); 
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    $stmt->bind_result($latitudine, $longitudine, $tip_problema);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $locatie = array(
    'latitudine'=>$latitudine,
    'longitudine'=>$longitudine,
    'tip_problema'=>$tip_problema
    );

    $response['error'] = false; 
    $response['message'] = 'Alerta raportata';
    $response['locatie'] = $locatie;    
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Eroare de identificare a alertelor';
}
```

Logically, there should be some kind of `while` that would go row by row, but as I am a beginner in `PHP` I couldn't implement any on my own. Searched some ways, but nothing worked for me. Thanks!

JSON code:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion

            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    JSONArray locatieArray = obj.getJSONArray("locatie");
                    for (int i = 0; i < locatieArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject locatie = locatieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // check latitudine and longitudine is not null and if not null then cast these values and call the addMarker() method.
                        if(!locatie.isNull("latitudine") && !locatie.isNull("longitudine")) {
                            latitudine_sql =Double.valueOf(locatie.getString("latitudine"));
                            longitudine_sql = Double.valueOf(locatie.getString("longitudine"));
                            addMarker(latitudine_sql, longitudine_sql); // this method is implemented below
                        }
                        tip_problema_sql = locatie.getString("tip_problema");
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must loop through results with a `while` loop and make `$response` a multidimensional array like this:

```
$problema = $_POST['problema'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT latitudine, longitudine, tip_problema FROM alerte WHERE tip_problema = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $problema);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); 
$response = array();
$x = 0;
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    $stmt->bind_result($latitudine, $longitudine, $tip_problema);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $x++;
        $locatie = array(
        'latitudine'=>$latitudine,
        'longitudine'=>$longitudine,
        'tip_problema'=>$tip_problema
        );

        $response[$x]['error'] = false; 
        $response[$x]['message'] = 'Alerta raportata';
        $response[$x]['locatie'] = $locatie;    
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Eroare de identificare a alertelor';
}
```

Note that in case of 0 results, `$response` will be a monodimensional array.

You can learn more about [`while` in the official documentation](https://php.net/while).

Comment: Yes, this method works. Thanks! Now I can fetch all the rows from db.

Comment: @Costin You're welcome! if for "all the rows" you mean "all the rows in that table without conditions" then `"SELECT latitudine, longitudine, tip_problema FROM alerte"` and remove the call to `bind_param`

Comment: Actually, I need the condition, so the markers appear according to the department. Now the problem it's that the app fetches all the rows, but doesn't add markers @user2342558

Comment: I am developing an app that gets the coordinates from database, and add markers on map on that specific points. I edited the question with the app code so be clearer. @user2342558

Comment: @Costin unfortunately I'm not able to support you for those markers, I suggest you to open a new question for that, instead of inserting it here where already there is a PHP question with a valid answer